# Tabulating the results in the terminal using PrettyTable

Tags: python, prettytable

I have the following code for the Babylonian method:

```
number = abs(float(125348))
guess = abs(float(600))

epsilon = 0.001

while True:
    difference = guess**2 - number
    print('{} : {}'.format(round(guess, 4), round(difference, 4)))
    if abs(difference) <= epsilon:
        break
    guess = (guess + number / guess) / 2.0
```

which gives the output

```
600.0 : 234652.0
404.4567 : 38237.1952
357.1868 : 2234.4368
354.059 : 9.7833
354.0452 : 0.0002
```

and I'd like to tabulate the results in the terminal, using PrettyTable, as such:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
t = PrettyTable(['Square Root', 'Difference'])
t.add_row(['600', 234652.0])
t.add_row(['404.4567', 38237.1952])
t.add_row(['357.1868', 2234.4368])
t.add_row(['354.059', 9.7833])
t.add_row(['354.0452', 0.0002])
print(t)

+-------------+------------+
| Square Root | Difference |
+-------------+------------+
|     600     |  234652.0  |
|   404.4567  | 38237.1952 |
|   357.1868  | 2234.4368  |
|   354.059   |   9.7833   |
|   354.0452  |   0.0002   |
+-------------+------------+
```

What would be the best way at going about combining both blocks of code, so it simultaneously tabulates the results for the square root? I'm open to feedback on my code as well, and I'm looking for ways to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will do what you want:

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable

number = 125348.0
guess = 600.0
epsilon = 0.001

t = PrettyTable(['Square Root', 'Difference'])
t.align['Square Root'] = 'r'
t.align['Difference'] = 'r'

while True:
    difference = guess ** 2 - number
    t.add_row(['%0.4f' % guess, '%0.4f' % difference])
    if abs(difference) <= epsilon:
        print(t)
        break
    guess = (guess + number / guess) / 2.0
```

Resulting in:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| Square Root |  Difference |
+-------------+-------------+
|    600.0000 | 234652.0000 |
|    404.4567 |  38237.1952 |
|    357.1868 |   2234.4368 |
|    354.0590 |      9.7833 |
|    354.0452 |      0.0002 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the `PrettyTable` instance and add the rows of the values the same way you have added in the sample block.

```py
number = abs(float(125348))
guess = abs(float(600))
epsilon = 0.001
t = PrettyTable(['Square Root', 'Difference'])       #<--- Create the table
while True:
    difference = guess**2 - number
    # print('{} : {}'.format(round(guess, 4), round(difference, 4)))
    t.add_row([round(guess, 4), round(difference, 4)]) #<---- Add the values to row
    if abs(difference) <= epsilon:
        break
    guess = (guess + number / guess) / 2.0
    
print(t)
+-------------+------------+
| Square Root | Difference |
+-------------+------------+
|    600.0    |  234652.0  |
|   404.4567  | 38237.1952 |
|   357.1868  | 2234.4368  |
|   354.059   |   9.7833   |
|   354.0452  |   0.0002   |
+-------------+------------+
```